# How to pass variables from Ansible inventory to role?

Tags: nginx, deployment, load-balancing, ansible

I have nginx load balancer role which has upstreams variable like below:

```
nginx_lb_upstreams: 
 - name: backend
   balancing_method: least_conn      
   servers:
    - address: 192.168.10.10
      weight: 3
    - address: 192.168.10.11
      weight: 2
```

In the inventory exists group "AppServers" with relevant weights for load balancing:

```
[AppServers]
192.168.77.10 weight=3
192.168.77.11 weight=2
192.168.77.12 weight=1
```

How correctly pass addresses of `AppServers` with relevant weights to `nginx_lb_upstreams`? Something like below but using loop or `with_items` statement:

```
nginx_lb_upstreams: 
 - name: backend
   balancing_method: least_conn      
   servers:
    - address: groups['AppServers']
      weight: groups['AppServers']['weight']
```

**UPD**: as workaround I'm using initializing `servers` as below:

```
nginx_lb_upstreams: 
 - name: backend
   balancing_method: least_conn      
   servers: "{{ groups['AppServers'] }}"
```

And in template use `hostvars`:

```
{% for server in upstream.servers %}
server {{ server }} {%- if hostvars[server].weight is defined %} weight={{ hostvars[server].weight }} {%- endif %};
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't generate a variable the way you want.  Well you might be able to using set_fact but that will be ugly.  In your role you can do something like:

```
- name: show configured lbs
  debug: msg="host {{item}} weight hostvars[item].weight"
  with_items: groups['AppServers']
```

See http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts for more info.